# Xamarin Crashing at EntryPoint

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Xamarin keeps crashing at the app entry point, it throws an *EntryPointNotFoundException* even in the basic hello world project. What is my issue?

I've tested the app on a couple emulators and some physical devices, with different versions of Android, the app ran on all the emulators and physical devices prior to the latest Xamarin Studio update

My Xamarin info:

```
Xamarin Studio Community
Version 6.0.1 (build 9)
Installation UUID: 81b3920a-a193-4867-92d2-654257758582
Runtime:
    Mono 4.4.1 (mono-4.4.0-branch-c7sr0/4747417) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 404010000

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 0.31.0
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 7.0.1 (8228)
Build 7A1001

Xamarin.Mac
Not Installed

Xamarin.iOS
Not Installed

Xamarin.Android
Version: 6.0.0.34 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/name/prerequest/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        4.1 (API level 16)
        4.4 (API level 19)
        5.0 (API level 21)
        6.0 (API level 23)

SDK Tools Version: 24.4.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 23.0.1
SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.2

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Xamarin Android Player
Version: 0.6.5
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Android Player.app
```

Application output:

```
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xb7b4ac08] -> mscorlib[0xb7ad0450]: 2
[Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
[Mono] DllImport loaded library '(null)'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_lref_log_new'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_lref_log_new'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_lref_log_new'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_lref_log_delete'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_lref_log_delete'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_lref_log_delete'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_gref_log_new'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] Probing '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] Found as '_monodroid_get_identity_hash_code'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed'.
[Mono] Probing 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed'.
[Mono] Could not find 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed' due to 'Could not find symbol 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed'.'.
[Mono] Probing 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed'.
[Mono] Could not find 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed' due to 'Could not find symbol 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed'.'.
[Mono] Probing 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA'.
[Mono] Could not find 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA' due to 'Could not find symbol 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA'.'.
[Mono] Probing 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA'.
[Mono] Could not find 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA' due to 'Could not find symbol 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA'.'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed'.
[Mono] Probing 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed'.
[Mono] Could not find 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed' due to 'Could not find symbol 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed'.'.
[Mono] Probing 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed'.
[Mono] Could not find 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed' due to 'Could not find symbol 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managed'.'.
[Mono] Probing 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA'.
[Mono] Could not find 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA' due to 'Could not find symbol 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA'.'.
[Mono] Probing 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA'.
[Mono] Could not find 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA' due to 'Could not find symbol 'monodroid_typemap_java_to_managedA'.'.
```

Exception:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update Xamarin.Android to latest does the trick.

Xamarin About:

```
Xamarin Studio Community
Version 6.0.1 (build 9)
Installation UUID: 81b3920a-a193-4867-92d2-654257758582
Runtime:
    Mono 4.4.1 (mono-4.4.0-branch-c7sr0/4747417) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 404010000

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 0.31.0
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 7.0.1 (8228)
Build 7A1001

Xamarin.Mac
Not Installed

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 9.8.1.4 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Hash: 3cf8aae
Branch: c7sr0
Build date: 2016-06-20 16:09:58-0400

Xamarin.Android
Version: 6.1.1.1 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/name/prerequest/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        4.1 (API level 16)
        4.4 (API level 19)
        5.0 (API level 21)
        6.0 (API level 23)

SDK Tools Version: 24.4.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 23.0.1
SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.2

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Xamarin Android Player
Version: 0.6.5
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Android Player.app

Build Information
Release ID: 600010009
Git revision: e879ce52093257c5c386ad7e390dfaa937fa7f90
Build date: 2016-06-24 11:53:43-04
Xamarin addins: a9252e6df4851fbbed1f9c6228e7b6dd1b475ac5
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle7-sr0

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.11.3
Darwin CDN.local 15.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0
    Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015
    root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```